# return statement in function that convert decimal to binary numbers

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm trying to understand how to use functions in JS.

This code converting decimal numbers to binary numbers:

```
for (j = 13; j <= 16; j++) {
  res = ""
  number = j

  while (number > 0) {
    res = res + number % 2
    number = Math.floor(number / 2)
  }

  len = res.length

  rev=""

  for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    rev = rev + res[res.length - i]
  }
  
  console.log(rev)
}
```

but when I'm trying to put this code into a function, the function returns only the first or the last value. What am I doing wrong?

```
function f(min, max) {
  for (j = min; j <= max; j++) {
    res = ""
    number = j
    
    while (number > 0) {
      res = res + number % 2
      number = Math.floor(number / 2)
    }

    len = res.length

    rev=""

    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
      rev = rev + res[res.length-i]     
    }  
  }
  return rev
}

console.log(f(13,15))
```

Comment: what result do you expect? an array? or an output for every number (as in the first code)?

Comment: In the first set of code, you call `console.log(rev)` inside the loop. In the function, you call `return rev` outside the loop.

Comment: Note that the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method of a number accepts a radix. Using `number.toString(2)` would simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the result of each iteration in array.

```
function f(min, max) {
  const results = []
  for (j = min; j <= max; j++) {
    res = ""
    number = j
    
    while (number > 0) {
      res = res + number % 2
      number = Math.floor(number / 2)
    }

    len = res.length

    rev=""

    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
      rev = rev + res[res.length-i]     
    }
    
    results.push(rev)
  }
  return results
}

console.log(f(13,15))
```

Also you should declare your variables in JavaScript, because not doing that can lead to bugs
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-happen-when-we-directly-assign-the-variable-without-declaring-it-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable for gathering all intermediate results.

You could take declarations for all variables.

```js
function f(min, max) {
    const result = [];
    for (let j = min; j <= max; j++) {
        let number = j,
            temp = "";
        while (number > 0) {
            temp += number % 2;
            number = Math.floor(number / 2);
        }
        result.push(temp);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(f(13, 15));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should divide your code into to functions

one that turn a number in binary string (I also included the existing js version)

and one that create a list of element between min and max and iterate onto them

```js
const toBin = n => n.toString(2)

const customToBin = n => {
  const res = []
  let number = n
  while (number > 0) {
    res.push(number % 2)
    number = Math.floor(number / 2)
  }
  return res.reverse().join('')
}

const createInterval = (min, max) => Array(max - min + 1).fill(min).map((_, i) => min + i)

const f = (min, max) => createInterval(min, max).map(customToBin)


console.log(f(13, 16))
```